# Cleaning up temp and bash + periodics

Tags: macos, terminal, maintenance

Every night, I run the following commands in `Terminal` before shutting down my Mac, but I wonder if I should just enter them in the same directory that my Terminal appears in (`/Users/myUserName`) or should I `cd` to a particular directory?

```
rm -rf ~/.bash_history
rm -rf .TemporaryItems
rm -rf .Trash
sudo periodic daily
sudo periodic weekly
sudo periodic monthly
history -c
```

Comment: Why not set HISTFILESIZE to zero?

Comment: Good suggestion. Thank you. I just learned about `HISTFILESIZE` now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring for a moment that the `daily, weekly, monthly` jobs are running automatically anyway, you need to make sure that you are either in the correct directory or using absolute paths when running `rm`:

```
rm -rf /PATH/TO/.TemporaryItems
rm -rf ~/.Trash
```

Comment: Thanks patrix. I am not trying to remove `temp`s from a specific directory. I thought this command would remove all the `temp`s that have been formed during the session your machine has been working. Is this not the case?

Comment: Not really. `rm` deletes specific files and folders. Temporary files get removed by the system automatically (after you log out, periodically or after a reboot).